# SPException :Trial of Product expired error at Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.ProfileManagerBase.ValidateLicensing()

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, central-administration, team-sites

I am getting

> Trial product expired error

when I want to open team site. Only settings page can be opened rest of pages I am getting error and stack trace is

```
Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.ProfileManagerBase.ValidateLicensing()
```

If unchecked the user profile service application under service connections,manage web application in central admin,the error will not occur. But we want user profile service.

I tried many ways like :

- To check the user profile synchronization is started  in central admin
- Creating new user profile service

but still no luck.

Answer (score 1):

Your license is not enterprise.

Go to central administration, Upgrade and migration and click on Convert farm license type and put a valid license key